# Rails server does not start in ubuntu bash for windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, rubygems

I'm trying to start the rails server in ubuntu bash but it does not start. I get the following error

> sysadmin@ACBPAW7-1543-JB:~/App/myapp$ rails server
>   }/home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:40:
>   warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions in
>   PATH, mode 040777
>   /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:51:
>   warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
>   /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:52:
>   warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
>   => Booting Puma
>   => Rails 5.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
>   => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:138:
>   warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated Exiting
>   /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.7/lib/rb-inotify/watcher.rb:74:in
>   `initialize': Invalid argument - Failed to watch
>   "/home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/locale":
>   the given event mask contains no legal events; or fd is not an inotify
>   file descriptor. (Errno::EINVAL)
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.7/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:190:in`
>   new'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.7/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:190:in
>   `watch'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.7/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:204:in`
>   watch'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/linux.rb:32:in
>   `_configure'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/base.rb:45:in`
>   block in configure'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/base.rb:40:in
>   `each'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/base.rb:40:in`
>   configure'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/base.rb:63:in
>   `start'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/backend.rb:28:in`
>   start'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/listener.rb:67:in `block in <class:Listener>'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/fsm.rb:120:in`
>   instance_eval'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/fsm.rb:120:in
>   `call'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/fsm.rb:91:in`
>   transition_with_callbacks!'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/fsm.rb:57:in
>   `transition'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/listener.rb:90:in`start'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/evented_file_update_checker.rb:90:in
>   `boot!'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/evented_file_update_checker.rb:61:in`
>   initialize'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb:59:in
>   `new'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb:59:in`
>   initialize_i18n'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb:15:in
>   `block in <class:Railtie>'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:41:in`
>   execute_hook'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in
>   `block in run_load_hooks'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in`
>   each'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in
>   `run_load_hooks'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:65:in`
>   block in '
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
>   `instance_exec'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`
>   run'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in
>   `block in run_initializers'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in`
>   block in tsort_each'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in
>   `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in`
>   each_strongly_connected_component_from'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in
>   `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in`
>   each'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in
>   `call'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in`
>   each_strongly_connected_component'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in
>   `tsort_each'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in`
>   tsort_each'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in
>   `run_initializers'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in`
>   initialize!'
>           from /home/sysadmin/App/myapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
>           from /home/sysadmin/App/myapp/config.ru:3:in`require_relative'
>           from /home/sysadmin/App/myapp/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in`
>   instance_eval'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in
>   `initialize'
>           from /home/sysadmin/App/myapp/config.ru:in`new'
>           from /home/sysadmin/App/myapp/config.ru:in `<main>'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in`
>   eval'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in
>   `new_from_string'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in`
>   parse_file'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:318:in
>   `build_app_and_options_from_config'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:218:in`
>   app'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in
>   `app'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:353:in`
>   wrapped_app'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:124:in
>   `log_to_stdout'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:77:in`
>   start'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in
>   `block in server'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in`
>   tap'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in
>   `server'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in`
>   run_command!'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>           from /home/sysadmin/App/myapp/bin/rails:9:in`require'
>           from /home/sysadmin/App/myapp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in`
>   load'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in
>   `call'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in`
>   call'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/bin/spring:49:in`
>   '
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in
>   `load'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in`
>   '
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'
>           from /home/sysadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'
>           from /home/sysadmin/App/myapp/bin/spring:14:in `<top (required)>'
>           from bin/rails:3:in`load'
>           from bin/rails:3:in `

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26054

Answer (score 3):

As per https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/10/07/wsl-adds-inotify-filesystem-change-notification-support/
filewatcher is not yet supported by BASH on Ubuntu on Windows, until Windows 10 OS Build 14942

Either install insider versions of Windows 10 or wait till official release of OS build greater than this version.

Untill then, you can solved this problem temporarily with commenting out last line (this)-

```
config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
```

in myappdirectory/config/environments/development.rb